# Can a same lombok builder be access/update by multiple threads?

Tags: multithreading, lombok

```
@Builder
public class X {
    @Nonnull String a;
    @Nonnull String b;
}
```

```
main () {
  X.XBuilder builder = X.builder();

  //thread 1
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(()-> {
        builder.a("some");
     });

  //thread 2
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(()-> {
        builder.b("thing");
     });
}
```

Here the same object is being accessed and modified at the same time.
So will this code be thread safe?

Usecase is like wants to call multiple api's, each api results is to populate the fields of class X.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: IMO this question is perfectly fine, it is in fact limited to one specific problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to know how the stuff that Lombok generates works, you can always use the [`delombok` tool](https://projectlombok.org/features/delombok).

With regard to thread safety of `@Builder`, you will see that you can in fact access a builder instance from multiple threads, but only under these constraints:

- Don't call the same field setter from different threads. Otherwise you'll never know which value makes it to the builder eventually.
- Make sure that all value-setting threads have terminated before you call `build()`. (If you want to call `build()` in a thread, too, make sure you create this thread after all value-setting threads have terminated.)

This is necessary because `@Builder` wasn't designed for concurrency (as that's not something you typically do with a builder). In particular, `@Builder` does not use synchronization or `volatile` fields, so you have to create a happens-before relation for all setter calls with the `build()` call.